# запись строки в массив через цикл

Tags: javascript

у меня было задание по смене регистра, при определенных условиях, со строки, это я выполнил, только не могу понять как результат заново собрать в одну строку

```js
function capsLock(str) {
    let splitedString = str.split(' ')

    for(let i = 0; i < splitedString.length; i++) {

        let splitedLetters = splitedString[i].split('')

        if(splitedLetters[0].match('[a-z]')) {
            for(let y = 1; y < splitedLetters.length; y++) {
                if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[a-z]')) {
                    console.log(splitedString[i]) 
                    break
                } else if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[A-Z]')) {
                    console.log(`${splitedLetters[0].toUpperCase()}${splitedString[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()}`)
                    break
                }
            }
        } else if(splitedLetters[0].match('[A-Z]')) {
            for(let y = 1; y < splitedLetters.length; y++) {
                if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[a-z]')) {
                    console.log(splitedString[i]) 
                    break
                } else if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[A-Z]')){
                    console.log(`${splitedLetters[0].toUpperCase()}${splitedString[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()}`) 
                    break
                }
            }
        }     
    }
}

capsLock('cAPS')
capsLock('Lock')
capsLock('wHY DO wE NEED cAPS lOCK?')
capsLock('FuNkY iS nOt CaPs!')
```

Comment: А где у вас результат?

Comment: у консоль выводит

Comment: Это не результат, а вывод в консоль. Сделайте результат.

Comment: простите, я только начал учить, и не до конца понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Ну я тоже не понимаю какой результат вы хотите собрать в строку, если результата никакого нет, а есть консоль-логи посреди кода.

Comment: Вам вместо консоль-логов всё в одну строчку собрать нужно, то что выводится в консоль?

Comment: там внизу вызов функции и надо чтобы строка состояла не из одного элемента, а допустим wHY DO wE NEED cAPS lOCK? в одной строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function capsLock(str) {
    let splitedString = str.split(' ');
    let resultStringsArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < splitedString.length; i++) {

        let splitedLetters = splitedString[i].split('')

        if(splitedLetters[0].match('[a-z]')) {
            for(let y = 1; y < splitedLetters.length; y++) {
                if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[a-z]')) {
                    resultStringsArray.push(splitedString[i]) 
                    break
                } else if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[A-Z]')) {
                    resultStringsArray.push(`${splitedLetters[0].toUpperCase()}${splitedString[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()}`)
                    break
                }
            }
        } else if(splitedLetters[0].match('[A-Z]')) {
            for(let y = 1; y < splitedLetters.length; y++) {
                if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[a-z]')) {
                    resultStringsArray.push(splitedString[i]) 
                    break
                } else if(splitedString[i].slice(1).match('[A-Z]')){
                    resultStringsArray.push(`${splitedLetters[0].toUpperCase()}${splitedString[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()}`) 
                    break
                }
            }
        }     
    }
    
    return resultStringsArray.join(' ');
}

console.log( capsLock('cAPS') );
console.log( capsLock('Lock') );
console.log( capsLock('wHY DO wE NEED cAPS lOCK?') );
console.log( capsLock('FuNkY iS nOt CaPs!') );
```

Comment: Вот смотрите, у функции появился результат, то что она возвращает

Comment: да именно так мне и нужно, спасибо большое